# How can we call middleware before urls.py

Tags: python, django

Middleware:

```
class NetworkCheckMiddleware:
    def __init__(self, get_response):
        self.get_response = get_response

    def __call__(self, request):

        domain = request.get_host()
        if not self.is_valid_domain(domain):
            return HttpResponseForbidden("Invalid Network")
        
        response = self.get_response(request)
        return response

    def is_valid_domain(self, domain):
        
        networkDomainModel = NetworkDomainModel.loadNetworkByDomain(domain)
        if networkDomainModel is None:
            return False
        
        obj = NetworkComponent()
        obj.setupNetwork(networkDomainModel.network_id)

        return True
```

NetworkComponent Class contains getId() methods

urls.py:

```
if NetworkComponent().getId() is not None:
    print(NetworkComponent().getId())
```

Getting None value while running the server.

Comment: did you add the middleware in the MIDDLEWARE settings.py variable?

Comment: @CarlosOsuna Yes its added 
    `common.middleware.networkcheck.NetworkCheckMiddleware`